# C# Sending encrypted emails to distribution list

Tags: c#, encryption

I have a requirement to send encrypted email to a distribution list. I am able to send encrypted emails to individual user addresses by fetching their email encryption certificate from the certificate store, but unable to figure out how to send an encrypted email to a distribution list.

Thanks.

Comment: Iterate trough the distribution list's individual mail addresses.

Comment: pgp supports encrypting a symmetric key with multiple public keys.  What library are you using to do encryption?

Comment: Hi,I am using using System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates; "EnvelopedCms"  to encrypt emails.